# Xander - getUniqueStarts.py - Print statement produce a SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to use Xander gene assembler (https://github.com/rdpstaff/Xander_assembler), but I have this error using getUniqueStarts.py (https://github.com/rdpstaff/Xander_assembler/blob/master/pythonscripts/getUniqueStarts.py):

```
File "/my/path/Xander_assembler//pythonscripts/getUniqueStarts.py", line 41
    print "%s" % (s[0])
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The line 41 is: `print "%s" %(s[0])`

I have the same error with Python 2.7.15 and 3.6. Developers recommend 2.7+ Python version. Something is wrong with the code? I appreciate your help.

Regards.

Comment: Are you sure your environment isn't defaulting to your Python 3.6 installation? `print` became a function in Python 3 and will require parentheses.

Comment: errors means you always run it with Python 3.x - In Python 2 it would work.